Why are Management Information Systems journals publishing so few operations management interdisciplinary research works?
I am new to Management Information Systems (MIS) research. Before embarking upon my research journey, my prior education and work experience has been in logistics and operations management.
My first impression looking at Information Systems journals like MIS Quaterly, Journal of Information Technology, Journal of MIS, etc, is that they almost avoid publishing works related to operations management. Why is this the case?
I plan to carry out an interdisciplinary research between Operations Management (OM) and Information Systems. But given the fact that prominent IS journals dont publish OM works, I am starting to get worried. What should I do? Or am I looking at the entire situation from a wrong perspective?
